# PlayerPaddle won't stop spinning

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to rotate my paddle once at a keypress, but at the moment, my turnLeft() won't stop spinning my paddle, while my turnRight() won't even start.

Here is where I call this in my GameScene.

```
class GameScreen(SceneBase):

    def __init__(self):
        SceneBase.__init__(self)

        self.player_paddle = classes.PlayerPaddle(screen_size)
        self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)

    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.player_paddle.direction = -1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.player_paddle.direction = 1      
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.player_paddle.turnLeft()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.player_paddle.turnRight()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP and self.player_paddle.direction == -1:
                    self.player_paddle.direction = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and self.player_paddle.direction == 1:
                    self.player_paddle.direction = 0

    def Update(self):
        self.player_paddle.update()
```

And Here is my image class, which PlayerPaddle inherits from.

```
class Image(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, color=(255,0,0)):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen_size = screen_size


        self.angle = 0
        #self.dir = 0

        self.original_image = pygame.image.load('naruto.png').convert()
        self.colorkey = self.original_image.get_at((0,0))

        self.original_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.original_image, (20, 100))
        self.rect = self.original_image.get_rect()

        self.update()


    def turnLeft(self):

        self.angle = (self.angle - 45) % 360


    def turnRight(self):
        print("entered")
        self.angle = (self.angle + 30) % 360


    def update(self):

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(self.colorkey)


        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = screen_rect.center)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

        self.olist = self.mask.outline()

        if self.olist:
            pygame.draw.lines(self.image, (0, 0, 0), 3, self.olist)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.original_image, self.rect)
```

Along with my PlayerPaddle class:

```
class PlayerPaddle(Image):

    def __init__(self, screen_size, color = (255,0,0)):

        self.centerx = 10
        self.centery = screen_size[1] // 2

        self.height = 100
        self.width = 20

        self.speed = 3
        self.direction = 0


        super().__init__(screen_size, color = (255, 0, 0))

    def update(self):

        super().update()
        self.centery += self.direction*self.speed

        self.rect.center = (self.centerx, self.centery)

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

        if self.rect.bottom > self.screen_size[1]-1:
            self.rect.bottom = self.screen_size[1]-1
```

I tested my rotation code in another file and it worked perfectly (one key press is one rotation) so I am currently befuddled as to why this is happening right now.

EDIT: SceneBase class

```
class SceneBase:
    number_of_players = None
    is_game_over = False 
    third_player_mode = None 

    def __init__(self):
        self.next = self

    def ProcessInput(self, events, pressed_keys):
        pass

    def Update(self):
        pass

    def Render(self, screen):
        pass

    def SwitchToScene(self, next_scene):
        self.next = next_scene

    def Terminate(self):
        self.SwitchToScene(None)
```

Comment: BTW: I think you should use only `self.dir` or only `self.angle` - you don't need both to rotate it

Comment: as always you can use `print()` in many places to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - it helps to find problem (and you don't have to learn how to use debuger)

Comment: you have almost the same code in `turnLeft`, `turnRight` and `update()`. See [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself. You should change `self.angle` in `turnLeft`, `turnRight` and call `update()`. Or even you could change angle without calling `update()` because `GameScreen.Update()` will do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with your `self.dir` variable.  I would expect a turning function to simply apply a turn for every iteration its called, not update the turn value itself after wards.  Lets think about this.  You have *three* functions that will turn the character.   Two only called when you press left or right, and one that is called *everysingle iteration,* `character.update()`.

So if you press left or right, assuming your turn functions apply a rotate properly (they don't) you'll just get a continuous rotation:

```
 def update(self):

    self.angle = (self.angle + self.dir) % 360
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle).convert()
```

Now the issue is that when you first call either turn operation you won't rotate at all.  In each function you set your `angle` (which is actually your real rotation angle, its what gets passed into the pygame transform function) to 0, and then update it with `(self.angle + self.dir) % 360` and since self.dir also starts at zero, you again are left with zero...

So at the start, the very first instance of your turn event, you won't actually turn anything.   Then you do something odd...

```
    self.dir -= 45
    if self.dir < 0:
        self.dir = 315
```

So, you start out with `self.dir = 315` on the next event for turn left, `(0 + 315) % 360 = 315` so you just rotated your entire image 315 degrees. Oh and now you will also be rotating your image by 315 degrees constantly in your update function as well, since it is always called, and you update `self.angle` with + `self.dir` every time, which stays 315 until you press the event key again.

So don't update that in the update function if you don't want that to happen constantly.

Finally, if you then go ahead and press the right button, you won't actually turn right, well, ever because your [angles are always positive](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate).  pygame requires negative angles for opposite rotations.

So how do you fix this?

1. don't update the rotation in the `update()` function to stop constant rotation
2. offset the current angle by a **constant** value ( like 10 or 30 degrees) in the direction you want. Don't use `self.dir`, change the sign on your angle, and figure out the positive or negative angle to rotate to for the pygame.transform.rotate.

Eg, if you want to rotate it counter clock wise, simply use the normal positive angle value, add the value of the angle you want to use, add 360 if its negative, and do % 360 like before

If you want to rotate clock wise, subtract your constant value from your `self.angle` then subtract 360 if its positive, and % -360

Comment: I made the rotation changes to my code and removed the redundant call from update(). However, now my paddle is flying off the screen, which is weird because I already put the restrictions on boundaries. I think this may have something to do with my self.rect. Please see the edits to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem probably is because in `update()` you have

```
 self.angle = (self.angle + self.dir) % 360
```

and `update()` is executed in every loop.

You should change angle only in `turnLeft` and `turnRight`, not in `update()`

---

**BTW:** you don't need `self.dir` and `self.angle` because both do the same.

You rather need

in `turnLeft()` "minus 45"

```
 self.angle = (self.angle - 45) % 360
```

in `turnRight()` "plus 45"

```
 self.angle = (self.angle + 45) % 360
```

---

As I wrote in comment in `turnLeft` and `turnRigth` you should only change angle and eventually call `update()`.

But it seems `GameScene.Update()` calls `update()` automatically so probably you don't need to call `update()` in `turnLeft` and `turnRigth`.

Comment: I made the rotation changes to my code and removed the redundant call from update(). However, now my paddle is flying off the screen, which is weird because I already put the restrictions on boundaries. I think this may have something to do with my self.rect

Comment: I though about something different - remove repeated code from `turnLeft`, and `turnRight` and keep it only in `update()`. `__Init__()` need this code in `update()`. In `turnLeft`, and `turnRight` you should only change `self.angle` without rotating image. I didn't show class `SceneBase` but I thing  `GameScene.Update()` should execute `update()` when it is needed. And I repeat again: if there are problem then use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is execute - it helps to resolve problem and you don't have to ask others.

Comment: The rotation doesn't seem to work. It's not rotating off the center axis. Instead, the paddle is just moving from side to side. I've also added the SceneBase Class. Also, I've been using print statements but they haven't been helping me debug. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: you have to use `print()` to display values in variables and then you can see if they are correct. And use `print()` to see if it executes function in correct order, and if it executes `if` or `elif` (or `for` or `while`) - if it executes `if` but it should execute `else` then you see that there is something wrong. And then you can use `print()` to display value returned by comparitons ie. `print("DEBUG: if A==B:", A, B, A==B)`

Comment: BTW: you could create repo on GitHub with all code and then we can download last version, run it and see all code. Now we have to ask you for other elements when we have to see them.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use github right now but i have uploaded my files to a google docs link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jNe9UCGv83ZefZlGa-cZrFlGq_iUWwIA

Comment: Thank you! How do you know which error to debug when a program like mine has so many errors?

Comment: error message shows in which file and in which line is problem and where this code was executed. If I add many `print()` with usfull messages then I can get more information - BTW: I left some `print("DEBUG: ...")` in code. Normally I display not only which method is executed but also use strings like `("before IF A==B", A, B, A==B)`, `"inside IF"`, `"after FOR"`, `("angle:", angle, type(angle))`